# EF5 ObjectResult to ObjectQuery is null?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to get the query string with parameters for debugging purposes from entity framework. No, I will not use EFProfiler because the query strings need to be visible as an output on the page. Most of those queries are written manually, using ExecuteStoredQuery(). However, casting them to ObjectQuery yields null.

Example:

```
ObjectResult<Parent> model = _context.ObjectContext().ExecuteStoreQuery<Parent>("SELECT * FROM Parents");
var objectQuery = model.AsQueryable() as ObjectQuery<Parent>;
```

objectQuery is null. ObjectContext() is a simple method in the datacontext that looks like:

```
return (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
```

I have exhausted my own ideas and anything that is yielded back from searches is... well, useless, because nobody seems to get that problem. Mind, the results come back correctly from the query.

Edit: Right, I should have mentioned this, as well.

Doing this:

```
var oq = m as ObjectQuery<Parent>;
```

Yields me this:

Cannot convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Whence is when I thought it needed to be cast AsQueryable(), which, well... is null, for obvious reasons. It was my tired head that forgot to add this little detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other anwers made clear that you can't cast an `ObjectResult<T>` to an `ObjectQuery<T>`. But I'm interested in your comment

> I tried CreateQuery and I ran into problems with it. For one, it doesn't like when the user tries to SELECT *, you seem to have to specify all the fields you need to get.

You can use an `ObjectQuery` to do a "*" search:

```
ObjectContext().ObjectQuery<Parent>("SELECT VALUE par FROM Parents AS par")
```

As you see, there is no actual `*` in the query string and the trace string doesn't have a `*` but shows all fields. But you don't have to specify all field to build the query string. I hope this will help you to make better use of `ObjectQuery`.

Comment: i think you mean `can´t cast` instead of `can cast`?

Answer (score 0):

Your cast `as ObjectQuery<Parent>` is not correct, cause `ObjectResult<Parent>.AsQueryable()` will return an `IQueryable<Parent>` that is not of type `ObjectQuery<Parent>`.

AsQueryable is the extension method of the class [Queryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx) that converts an IEnumerable to an IQueryable.

The result is that your variable objectQuery is null.

Comment: I have updated the original question with this forgotten detail, it's not allowing me to cast original m as objectquery.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you ACTUALLY want to use CreateQuery(sql) rather than ExecuteStoreQuery(sql).

Given the name, ExecuteStoreQuery actually runs the SQL, whilst CreateQuery returns an ObjectQuery ready to be sent to the database.

Obviously you can then call Execute on ObjectQuery to return the ObjectResult

Comment: I tried CreateQuery and I ran into problems with it. For one, it doesn't like when the user tries to SELECT *, you seem to _have_ to specify all the fields you need to get (which is unacceptable from the standpoint of the application). In addition, all the examples I've seen that allow using ToTraceString() have been using ExecuteStoreQuery() and then casting that to ObjectQuery :/ I'm not quite sure what is going on at the back end.